# Combining 2 SQL queries where each row from the first is a parameter for the second

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently running a SQL statement like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Members
WHERE Name LIKE "Bob"
```

And then looping through each result and running a second SQL such as:

```
@MemberNumber int

SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM Accounts
 WHERE MemberNumber = @MemberNumber AND Type = "SomeType") As "Type 1",
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM Accounts a
 INNER JOIN Table2 b on a.SOMETHING = b.SOMETHING
 WHERE a.MemberNumber = @MemberNumber AND b.Foo = "Bar") As "Type 2"
FROM dual
```

There has to be a way to combine these queries so I change 300 queries into 1, I just can't seem to figure out a way.

Comment: Is this really Oracle? AFAIK Oracle does not support Boolean in SQL in any version.

Comment: It's oracle but I wrote the example quickly without checking. I'll edit the example as to not confuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one direct method:

```
SELECT m.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Accounts a
        WHERE a.MemberNumber = m.MemberNumber AND Type = 'SomeType'
       ) As "Type 1",
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM Accounts a INNER JOIN
             Table2 b 
             ON a.SOMETHING = b.SOMETHING
        WHERE a.MemberNumber = m.MemberNumber AND b.Foo = 'Bar'
       ) As "Type 2"
FROM Members m
WHERE NewMember = true
```

Comment: Thanks... not sure why something so simple was eluding me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM Accounts
 WHERE MemberNumber IN (SELECT MemberNumber FROM Members WHERE NewMember = true) AND Type = "SomeType") As "Type 1",
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM Accounts a
 INNER JOIN Table2 b on a.SOMETHING = b.SOMETHING
 WHERE a.MemberNumber IN (SELECT MemberNumber FROM Members WHERE NewMember = true) AND b.Foo = "Bar") As "Type 2"
FROM dual
```